# How do I make a Webhook when trying to make a Facebook bot?

Tags: facebook, bots

I am trying to make my own messenger bot, and I am fairly new to the world of code. I have done a lot of digging but I cannot seem to find anything relating to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart, Step 2. I don't understand where you get the Webhook from? I am also trying to use their Wit.ai, but I still do not understand how I connect all these dots! Thank you!

Comment: You set up a server that can handle the requests that Facebook will send you.

Comment: @WizKid Can you link me to a tutorial or something that could help?

Comment: You create a server that responds to HTTP requests. It is nothing special with messenger bots

Answer (score 0):

In fact, to config the webhook, you choose the URL and your verify token. Then, the url file receive a GET parameters `{"hub_mode":"subscribe","hub_challenge":"00000000","hub_verify_token":"pass_phrase"}`, you verify the parameter `"hub_verify_token"` is the same than choose and your return the parameter `"hub_challenge"` if it's good. And your Webhooks is validate

Answer (score 0):

You have to create server for their HTTPS requests (you need SSL certificate on that domain) and then you have to implement code or you can use [my API](https://github.com/Fritak/messenger-platform) in PHP:

```
// Check if request is subscribe and then return challenge
if($bot->checkSubscribe())
{
    print $bot->request->getChallenge();
    exit;
}
```

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation#setup_webhook):

> Under the "PRODUCT SETTINGS" section, click on the "Messenger" product you just added, find the Webhooks section and click Setup Webhooks. Enter a URL for a webhook, enter a Verify Token and select message_deliveries, messages, messaging_optins, and messaging_postbacks under Subscription Fields.
>
> At your webhook URL, add code for verification. Your code should look for the Verify Token and respond with the challenge sent in the verification request. Click Verify and Save in the New Page Subscription to call your webhook with a GET request.